# TensorFlow not found in Jupyter lab

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-lab

Here's what I did:

Installed python

Installed virtualenv using pip

Installed jupyterlab using pip

Created a virtualenv named tf at a local dir

Installed Nvidia CUDA and CUDNN following the official documentation

Installed tensorflow-gpu in the virtualenv

Installed an ipython kernel in the virtualenv

Launched jupyterlab through terminal

Created new notebook named Tensorflow-jpnb.ipynb

But for some reason I can't import tensorflow in Jupyter lab.
It works in Pycharm but not in Jupyter lab.

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x
UsageError: Line magic function `%tensorflow_version` not found.
```

```
import tensorflow as tf
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [3], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 import tensorflow as tf

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

I even tried installing Jupyter lab in the virtualenv but it was to no avail.

What can I do except install Anaconda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What can I do except install Anaconda?

Actually that's a terrific answer. I recommend it.
Remember to use `$ conda activate myproject`
prior to starting a kernel with `$ jupyter notebook`.

Conda solves a larger set of problems
than what pip tackles,
including binary dependencies for tensorflow and related libraries.

---

> can't import tensorflow in Jupyter lab. It works in Pycharm but not in Jupyter lab.

You're saying that

```
$ python -c 'import tensorflow'
```

fails with `No module named 'tensorflow'`.
Ok, how to debug that?

Start with this pair of commands:

1. `$ which python`
2. `$ python -m site` (or simply print sys.path)

That will help you verify that you are running the
desired interpreter (due to `${PATH}`)
and that it has a suitable `sys.path` for `import`s (due to `${PYTHONPATH}`).

If `which` reports e.g. `/usr/bin/python`, well, that's bad,
it indicates you neglected to use your venv or conda project
where things like tensorflow have been carefully installed.

---

tl;dr: Your env vars are not always the same when
you invoke python, and you want to ensure that they are
so TF will be available.

Comment: Thankyou for your help but it worked somehow. Idk how but I gave up last night woke up today to solve it and just tried importing again. It worked.